# Ajax POST error (400 BAD REQUEST)

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, error-handling

and thank you in advance for helping me.

I'm trying to make a POST where I pass the TOKEN in  the URL and I want to pass another param too so I can save the info in the DB. I have this:

```
    $("#btnAddCompany").click(function(e) {
    var token = "123";
    var companyValue = document.getElementById("companyValue").value;
    var obj ={CompanyId: 4 ,Name: companyValue }
    var postData = JSON.stringify(obj);
    console.log(postData);
      $.ajax({  
        type: "POST", //REQUEST TYPE
        dataType: "json", //RESPONSE TYPE
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: postData,
        url: "http://banametric.ddns.net/BanaMetricWebServices/BanaSov_WS.svc/CompanySave/"+token, 
        success: function(data) {
            toastr.success("Lidl Adicionado!");
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        }
    }).always(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus != "success") {
            alert("Error: " + jqXHR.statusText);
        }
    })
});
```

But I'm getting an 400 error (Bad Request) so I assume that I'm making something wrong, but I don't find out what. The error trace is this:

> AJAX error in request: {   "readyState": 4,   "responseText": "\r\n
>
> The server encountered an error processing the request. The
>   exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message
>   format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are
>   'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been
>   configured on the binding. See server logs for more
>   details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> \r\n
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at

Comment: You can try contentType: "application/json"

Comment: @bipinpatel I've tryed it and now I'm getting another error. 405(Method not allowed)

Answer (score 1):

It's error because of

> The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'.
>   So you can pass contentType in your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
 ....,

  contentType: "application/json"
})
```

Comment: I've tryed it and now I'm getting another error. 405(Method not allowed)

Comment: Which backend do you use c# or other?

Comment: I use C# yes. All my backed is in C#

Comment: You can try with data: obj, (without JSON.stringfy) I don't know it's working or not but just try.it's your data format issue

Comment: Nop, not working anyway, I know that the problem is in my data formate, but I cannot discover where. I've alrady posted the backend structure so you can try to analyse that with me. Thank you in advance bud...

Comment: Welcome anytime.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it depends on what server wants to read from you.

Server does not want to read raw bytes, it wants xml or json

Try to add headers like

```
beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
},
```

in $.ajax() function

Comment: the "accept" header is for what the client expects back from the server and isn't relevant to this. Besides the `datatype: "json"` in the existing ajax code already sets this header. However setting the content-type header is a good idea, yes

Comment: @ADyson I've already tryed to add the ContentType and now I'm getting another kind of error. Error 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Of course, I write it just for example) I suppose setting 'contentType: "application/json"' is likely enough to solve your problem.

Comment: @R.Quintal, try another method (PUT,PATCH,etc). You should have API (docs) of your server.

Comment: I'll try to fix it but now I'm getting an 405 error. And I've already updated my code. I'm going crazy about this.

Comment: @R.Quintal If you're getting a 405 then check that you're using the correct HTTP method as defined by the API's docs (likely to be one of GET, POST, PUT, DELETE). Also if this is a cross-domain request check that the API server allows CORS requests.

Comment: Yes I gess I'm using the right one. This is what my API says: //CompanySAVE

        [OperationContract]

        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",UriTemplate = "CompanySave/{Token}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]

        void CompanySave(DataModal.Main.Company company, string Token);

And yes, the API allows CORS requests.

Comment: @R.Quintal, sorry for stupid question, but are you sure you use POST method? Your example script has "PUT". 
P.s. sorry for stupid question in advance=)

Comment: @OlegKorobov Yes, I'm using POST method. You right when you said that I typed PUT in the example, but it was my mistake. Already changed it.

Comment: @R.Quintal, you said that api let you CORS. But you can also try to add 'crossDomain: true,' in your ajax() . Check may it helps)

Comment: @OlegKorobov I've tryed it but it doesn't work anyway. I have a lot of other methods making use of CORS and all of that went fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content type header in your request to inform the server you're sending the data as JSON.

The error message is telling you that the server does not understand the content you're sending it - you have to give it a hint that the data is in a particular format, especially because, again as mentioned in the error message, it allows you to submit in more than one different format (JSON or XML in this case).

Adding

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

to the options in your $.ajax call should resolve the issue.

P.S. We can't see the signature of your controller method but it's possible you may also need to give your parameter a name within the JSON, e.g. something like `data: JSON.stringify({ "companyValue": postData });` , but there's not enough info in your question to say for certain what the correct structure should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on("submit", ".example_form", function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/{ROUTE_URL}',
    data: new FormData(this),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    /* OR contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"*/
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this

```
 var postData = JSON.stringify(companyValue);
```

why don't you try this:

```
var obj ={token :token ,companyValue:companyValue }
```

And then make use of the json stringify function

```
 var postData = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

After that in ajax call only change the url:

```
url: "http://webservice/CompanySave/"
```

Comment: that's just a guess because you don't know the signature of the method. Possibly `token` is intended to be within the URL, we cannot know that from the information available. It also doesn't fix the fact that the server doesn't understand the data format being sent.

Comment: @EvilsEmpire The token is intended to be in the URL.